# How to look for user from input and create user if don't exist

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm trying to create a shell script that ask for user input. If the user exist it lets you know; if the user doesn't exist it creates the user and password and adds them to a group. However, I am stuck and am hoping someone can assist. It seems to stop after it reads the response and doesn't execute the *if/then*

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Which user would you like to use docker? "
read -r user

getent passwd "$user" > /dev/null 2&>1 && echo yes || echo no
read -r response

if [ "$response" == "yes" ];then
        echo " User already exist"
if [ "$response" == "no" ];then
        useradd -m $user
        passwd $user
        usermod -aG docker $user
fi
fi
```

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I did. Hence the reason why I posted here for more assistance. I'm a bash shell script noob.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to output `yes` or `no`; the `if` statement can test the exit status of `getent` just as `&&` does.

```
echo "Which user would you like to use docker? "
IFS= read -r user

if getent passwd "$user" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "User already exists"
else
    useradd -m "$user" &&
    passwd "$user" &&
    usermod -aG docker "$user"
fi
```

Comment: It specifies the character(s) to use for field splitting. In this case, setting it to null preserves any leading or trailing whitespace that might occur in the input. This might be a place where you *want* to discard it, but given that there are still lots of ways to enter an invalid user name, it's good practice to use it unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a random password or also set a password like below, I guess the passwd command is the problem here for it expect a response in your example:

```
#!/bin/bash

group="docker"
password1="$(strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 8 | tr -d '\n';echo)"

read -p "Which user would you like to use docker: " user
grep -q ${user} /etc/passwd 

# If grep command was true, we know user exist
if [[ "$?" = "0" ]];then
    echo "${user} already exist"
else
    # We can use 'read -p' instead of using echo + read
    read -p "Add a password for ${user}: " password

    # We can use -m and -G in same line
    useradd -m ${user} -G ${group}

    # Use read -p for set a password or use password1 for a random pass
    chpasswd <<< ${user}:${password}

    # Another way to add password without passwd
    # echo ${user}:${password} | chpasswd

    # Let us know user was added in group docker and with a password
    echo "Successfully added ${user}/${group} and password has been set to ${password}......."

fi
```

Comment: `2&>1` creates a file with name `1`. I suggest to use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout.